# Mobile Site Isn't Displaying Correctly

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

So I'm having an issue where my site has a lot of padding on the right side, making the layout load incorrectly. It appears correctly in on my desktop when the window is resized, but everything other than the header breaks when viewed on my phone. All of the relevant divs are set to a width of 480px, and I have the following tag in my header for the media query:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Here are screenshots of how it appears on desktop and mobile, as well as a link to my mobile css page (the menu is open on mobile, but the extra space seems to affect it as well).

[CSS Page](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2h7ycTEcgMVX3hRUk9QWUc4eXc)

Edit: I'm now having a slightly different issue, where the margin has been added to the entire right side of the screen. I changed the pixel widths for many of the divs to 100%, as well as adding the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">` tag to the header. While they can no longer zoom out, you can just scroll the screen horizontally to find the padding. I'm also having an issue with my font-face tag, which no longer loads the header fonts. I updated the css file, so hopefully that shows why it won't work anymore.

[image: Mobile]

Also, here's a link to the live site: [Link](http://jordanwebdesign.x10host.com/itops/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting explicit widths here, (at least not in pixels anyway) and from a brief glance at what you've posted I'd imagine that's where your issue lies.

Firstly, take off the widths that you've set for anything that you intend on being "full width" - remember divs are block-level elements anyway, so if you don't set a width at all, they'll have a width of 100%.

Secondly, take off any other pixel widths you're setting and change them to be percentages instead.

Thirdly, you'll save yourself a lot of headaches if you set 'box-sizing' to 'border-box' (I'd recommend just doing it on '*' for simplicity). This will prevent your padding and margin from being added on top of any widths you set as percentages; they'll be included in the box sizing instead.

Finally, I can't stress enough how important it is to get out of the mindset of things like "mobile" and "desktop". All we're talking about here is different viewport sizes. :)

If you have a live link you can share I'd be more than happy to have a proper look at this.

Comment: I switched the major divs to percentage widths, but that didn't seem to affect it. The live version is hosted [here](http://jordanwebdesign.x10host.com/itops/).

Comment: Switching to % widths seems to have helped, but you can still zoom out from the page and offset the layout. Otherwise it appears to be working properly.

Comment: So I'm having a similar issue, but the padding has been added to the entire right side of the screen. I added the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">` tag to the home page in an attempt to prevent zooming out and to fix it, but now you can just move it to find the extra space.

Comment: Don't add user-scalable=no *or* maximum-scale=1 - both of these things are terrible for accessibility; you shouldn't be preventing users from doing things. Let me have a look at it now. :)

Comment: Okay, just looked - it's the image that you have at the bottom. Change the max-width on that (and all images) to be 100% and that should sort it for you. :)

Comment: For future reference, when you have issues like this, the easiest thing to do is to scroll to the right (to the bit that you shouldn't be able to get to), and then just walk down the DOM tree until you find what's sticking out. In this case it was easy because the image was there and easy to see, but often it's rogue padding or margins that cause this sort of thing. :) 

But seriously, build things for the smallest-viewport before anything else. Use min-widths rather than max-widths. Trust me, your life will be easier for it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your .css file:

```
img{max-width:100% !important}
```

Comment: No, don't do this. This is a hack, we need to figure out what the actual problem is. :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread your reply. Still absolutely don't put the !important flag in, but yes it is the img that's the problem. :)

Comment: !important is not a hack - it just overwrites other possibly incorrect values and can do absolutely no harm (an image cannot have more than 100% width anyway).

Comment: I misread your original reply (as I said in my second reply) - I hastily read it thinking you were suggesting setting max-width on body, which I see a lot in people struggling with RWD.

However, overcoming issues with !important is not a good way to do anything in my opinion. It prevents your styles from cascading, and can lead to difficult to debug issues further down the line.